# accessing a java webservice from the webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to access a java webservice by sending a soap request to the service
the strange part is that until recently it worked fine, and now it gives me an internal server error
what am i doing wrong ??

this is my soap message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q0="http://webservice.lenabru.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <soapenv:Body> <q0:register><q0:regFirstName></q0:regFirstName><q0:regLastName></q0:regLastName><q0:regLoginName></q0:regLoginName><q0:regPassword></q0:regPassword><q0:regAddress></q0:regAddress><q0:regEmail></q0:regEmail><q0:regPhone></q0:regPhone></q0:register></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

and this is the response i get from the server

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
   <faultstring>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">Lena</ns1:hostname>
   </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

this is the contents of the webmethod i am trying to reach:

```
@WebMethod
    public boolean register(String regFirstName, String regLastName, String regLoginName, String regPassword, String regAddress, String regPhone, String regEmail) {
        return false;
    }
```

this is my wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://webservice.lenabru.com" xmlns:intf="http://webservice.lenabru.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://webservice.lenabru.com">
<!--
WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)
-->
<wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://webservice.lenabru.com">
<element name="register">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="regFirstName" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="regLastName" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="regLoginName" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="regPassword" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="regAddress" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="regPhone" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="regEmail" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="registerResponse">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="registerReturn" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="isUserExists">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="userName" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="isUserExistsResponse">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="isUserExistsReturn" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
</schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="isUserExistsResponse">
<wsdl:part element="impl:isUserExistsResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="registerRequest">
<wsdl:part element="impl:register" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="isUserExistsRequest">
<wsdl:part element="impl:isUserExists" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="registerResponse">
<wsdl:part element="impl:registerResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ElectronicArenaWebService">
<wsdl:operation name="register">
<wsdl:input message="impl:registerRequest" name="registerRequest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="impl:registerResponse" name="registerResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="isUserExists">
<wsdl:input message="impl:isUserExistsRequest" name="isUserExistsRequest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="impl:isUserExistsResponse" name="isUserExistsResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ElectronicArenaWebServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:ElectronicArenaWebService">
<wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="register">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input name="registerRequest">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="registerResponse">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="isUserExists">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input name="isUserExistsRequest">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="isUserExistsResponse">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ElectronicArenaWebServiceService">
<wsdl:port binding="impl:ElectronicArenaWebServiceSoapBinding" name="ElectronicArenaWebService">
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ElectronicArenaLena/services/ElectronicArenaWebService"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: can you post axis.log file (or whatever you called it)?

Comment: where do i find this file ?

Comment: usually it appears in the same location as other log files (well it might depend on the application server you are using) see http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/developers-guide.html#Configuring_the_Logger 
I have a question: are you restricted by JDK1.4 to use axis 1.4? 
regarding configuring it, you might need (if nothing worked) to download log4j jars (best from maven repository) http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j
and put log4j.properties in the classpath

Comment: how do i put log4j.properties in the classpath?

Comment: same location as the jars (you have in your CLASSPATH variable), this depends on the app server, but generally speaking, put it in the same folder as the jars you are using for this project in the app server (or just google log4j with "APP_SERVER_U_ARE_USING")

Comment: got your issue fixed?

Comment: yea , this code works perfectly
the problem with it was: the library which i was using to do all the work, wasn't exported when i exported the code to the server, which is why it failed. because i don't have good logging system installed, i had to find out the hard way ;)

Comment: if you can help me figure out how to place the logging system in, and post the answer, i will mark it accepted

Comment: what application server are you using?

Comment: tomcat 7 (this is added to make the comment long enough)

Answer (score 0):

First a note: if you're using Tomcat 7 (why not use Axis 2 ?)

Setup for Log4j (at the time axis 1 was still there there was log4j, now there is a better [alternatives](http://mike.vanvendeloo.net/2011/05/06/logging-which-framework-to-choose-log4j-commons-logging-logback-slf4j) from the same author of Log4j it's called logback - however there is a new [Log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) now but I haven't tested it for this setup only the one that comes with axis downloaded here 
http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis/1_4/)

create a log4j.properties file and put it in your WEB-INF/classes folder 
(I created a sample content so that you can get going, might need to look at log4j's documentation to modify the logs as you need - the below creates multiple log files(max 5) whenever one's size reaches 100k it creates another, you might need to change the size or number as needed or just use one)

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.File=axis.log 
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} – %m%n

# below line might not be needed, but I just had it there
log4j.R.org.apache.axis=DEBUG
```

now open axis.jar and remove whatever properties file you have directly in the folder structure (next to MANIFEST and org folders - I had simplelog.properties so I deleted it)

restart apache tomcat and check the apache logs to make sure log4j isn't throwing any warnings or errors

If everything works fine, you should be able to see axis.log in apache tomcat's **bin** directory

Note:
you might notice a lot of useless debug logs, however when an exception occurs or some issue happens it might be handy to have this level of details in your logs, plus you can disable it anytime you need, just replace rootLogger DEBUG into INFO or comment log4j.properties all together

References:

http://osdir.com/ml/text.xml.axis.user/2002-08/msg00436.html

http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/developers-guide.html#LoggingTracing